# add bootstrap label class from selected drop down list

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to change bootstrap label color when i select different label from dropdown.
see plunker for more clarification http://embed.plnkr.co/lpQdSrVanpE7xq2IiqqB/

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.label').html($(this).text() + ' <span  class="caret"></span>');
    $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.label').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Comment: It's easier to use `toggleClass()`. See this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714498/toggle-div-color-on-click

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
        $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.label').html($(this).text() + ' <span  class="caret"></span>').end().val($(this).data('value'));

     $("#dropdownMenu1").removeAttr('class').addClass($(this).attr("class"));;
    });
```

Comment: All you need to get the class of the currently clicked li and then remove your class of the label and add new class to it.