# Change text color when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a difficulty, a user click and it's not a background code, and clicking again has to go back to the previous one. This is happening, but doing all this again does not go, it's as if a jquery executes only once.

The even paragraphs have their color and the odd paragraphs have their color.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>

p:nth-child(2n+1){
  color: green;
    background-color: red;
}

p:nth-child(2n){
color: yellow;
background-color:blue;
}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>

<script>

      $('p:nth-child(2n+1)').click(function(){
     $(this).css('background-color','black').css('color','white');
     $('p:nth-child(2n+1)').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','red').css('color','green');
    });    
  });

    $('p:nth-child(2n)').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','black').css('color','white');
     $('p:nth-child(2n)').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','blue').css('color','yellow');
    });
   
  });


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is answered in this question i guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714498/toggle-div-color-on-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you don't need to register the click event two times, or separate things for odd and evens, and you can toggle a class :

```js
$(function(){
  // p:nth-child(2n), p:nth-child(2n+1)
  // p:even, p:odd
  // p
  $('p').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("blackwhite");
  });
});
```

```css
p:nth-child(2n+1){
  color: green;
  background-color: red;
}

p:nth-child(2n){
  color: yellow;
  background-color:blue;
}

p.blackwhite {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `function()` in your code.

You might want to check this: 
[Change background color of a page using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475422/change-background-color-of-a-page-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```js
$('p:nth-child(2n+1)').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('click-child'))
        $(this).removeClass('click-child').addClass('odd-child');
     else
        $(this).removeClass('odd-child').addClass('click-child');
});

$('p:nth-child(2n)').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('click-child'))
        $(this).removeClass('click-child').addClass('even-child');
     else
        $(this).removeClass('even-child').addClass('click-child');
});
```

```css
.odd-child{
color: yellow;
background-color:blue;
}

.even-child{
color: green;
background-color:red;
}

.click-child{
color: white;
background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="even-child">1</p>
<p class="odd-child">2</p>
<p class="even-child">3</p>
<p class="odd-child">4</p>
<p class="even-child">5</p>
<p class="odd-child">6</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as @nullqube answered `toggleClass` is the best approach, but it can be done with If-Else statements as well:

```js
$('p:nth-child(2n+1)').click(function(){
     if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'){
       $(this).css('background-color','red').css('color','green'); 
     } else {
       $(this).css('background-color','black').css('color','white');
     }
  });

  $('p:nth-child(2n)').click(function(){
     if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'){
       $(this).css('background-color','blue').css('color','yellow');      
     } else {
       $(this).css('background-color','black').css('color','white');
     }
  });
```

```css
p:nth-child(2n+1){
  color: green;
  background-color: red;
}

p:nth-child(2n){
  color: yellow;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
```