# css: change background color of child-div but not parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with three child divs.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> something </div>
  <div class="child"> something </div>
  <div class="child"> something </div>
</div>
```

This is what we need:

Click on the parent, the parent div gets a different `background-color` with `:active`
Click on a child, the child div gets a different background-color with :active

Problem: Both parent and child become active when clicked on the child and both get the different `background-color`.

I tried with `:active:not(:matches(parent))` but that didn't work.

Is this possible to solve without Jquery and if so, how?

Comment: Could you provide the CSS you have tried?

Comment: You cannot detect a click without Javascript, a hyperlink or form elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toggle div color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714498/toggle-div-color-on-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

Since the click itself on the div is already handled by jquery, and with the help of one of the posts here (can't find it anymore) I managed to solve the problem.

When the div is clicked I add a class called 'actief' to the div just before a window.href is set.

```
$(this).addClass('actief');
```

Then in css I added this:

```
.parent.actief {
   background-color: red;
}
.child.actief {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Since the click redirects to a new page, the colors are only set for a few milliseconds.

Thanks for all the help and suggestions.

Comment: I thought you're not going to use jquery?

Comment: uh yeah this is not what you asked of us

Comment: I meant not use jquery to do the css changes because those are centralizes in sass files. By putting a class on it, I could use the css.

Answer (score 0):

you can change its background using `:focus` and `tab-index`

```css
.child{
  padding: 5px;
}
.child:focus{
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" tabindex="1"> something </div>
  <div class="child" tabindex="2"> something </div>
  <div class="child" tabindex="3"> something </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `stopPropagation()` and it won't pass the click event to the parent as well

```js
$(".parent").click(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#E1F3F7");
})

$(".child").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).css("background-color", "#E7F7E1");
})
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> something </div>
  <div class="child"> something </div>
  <div class="child"> something </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a small question. How would you add to the jquery, if I wanted the color of a clicked div to dissapear once I click on another div and henceforth. This means only one background color shows at a time, like an active link. Because currently the color stays on all clicked classes. ideally I would only like 1 class to show color at a time, is there an easy work around?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to add a new child element you can try something like this..

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.parent:active {
  background-color: red;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.child:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
.underlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 1;
}
.child:active ~ .underlay {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> something </div>
  <div class="child"> something </div>
  <div class="child"> something </div>
  <div class="underlay"></div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/jsr9e7hd/